# How to fix OpenGL compile error, "unresolved external symbol"

Tags: visual-c++, linker-errors

I'm trying to write an OpenGL program to manipulate the camera. However the code isn't compiling.

[All of my source code can be found here](http://pastie.org/private/rrbwwzbennbjku8txiredq).

The error is:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Lab4, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 2/14/2011 7:17:54 PM.
1>_PrepareForClean:
1>  Deleting file "Debug\Lab4.lastbuildstate".
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\Lab4.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  camera.cpp
1>camera.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscalllVector3::normalize(void)" (?normalize@Vector3@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Camera::set(class Point3,class Point3,class Vector3)" (?set@Camera@@QAEXVPoint3@@0VVector3@@@Z)
1>camera.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class Vector3 __thiscall Vector3::cross(class Vector3)" (?cross@Vector3@@QAE?AV1@V1@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Camera::set(class Point3,class Point3,class Vector3)" (?set@Camera@@QAEXVPoint3@@0VVector3@@@Z)
1>camera.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: float __thiscall Vector3::dot(class Vector3)" (?dot@Vector3@@QAEMV1@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall Camera::setModelviewMatrix(void)" (?setModelviewMatrix@Camera@@AAEXXZ)
1>C:\Users\Andrew Davis\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Lab4\Debug\Lab4.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:01.08
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have this in my linker already:

opengl32.lib
glu32.lib
glut32.lib
freeglut.lib

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide a body for the following functions, even if it's empty.
`Vector3::normalize(), Vector3::cross(), Vector3::dot()` . For instance

```
void normalize(){ //do something}
```

You are calling them, so you get an unresolved linker error because there is no implementation.

Comment: I was getting most of my existing code from my Computer Graphics book. Could you be a bit more specific, I'm extremely new to OpenGL! I really appreciate your response!

Comment: Okay, I got it to work for normalize, but having trouble with cross & dot still.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with OpenGL or it's libraries.  It looks like if camera.cpp uses some different class, but its implementation is either not build or not linked.

**EDIT: Just took the look at your code**

How about implementing `Vector3::normalize()`, `Vector3::cross()` and `Vector3::dot()`? Lines 86, 107 and 108 in the Pastebin.

Comment: If you could, please read my comments on the other answer. I'm still having difficulty with this. Thanks!